# Adding validations on jWizard before proceeding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jwizard

The is the plugin: http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/
The initialization is as follows:

```
mywizard = $("#wizard").jWizard({
        menuEnable: true,
        counter: {enable: true},
        effects: {enable: true},
        buttons: {
            cancelHide: false,
            cancelType: "button",<button>
            finishType: "submit",
            cancelText: "Cancel", 
            previousText: "Back",
            nextText: "Next",
            finishText: "Submit"
        }
    });
```

I don't want the next button to show until some validations are done on each steps. I tried adding `$(".jw-next-button").bind("click", function(){ ... console.log('got here');... if(validation == 'bad') return false});` the console does get logged, but the wizard doesn't from moving forward. Any clues or tips on improving the strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the javascript file **jquery.jWizard.js**, find the following

```
updateMenu: function (firstStep) {
            var wizard = this,
                currentStep = this._stepIndex,
                $menu = this.element.find(".jw-menu");

            if (!firstStep) {
                this._effect($menu.find("li:eq(" + currentStep + ")"), "menu", "change");
            }

            $menu.find("a").each(function (x) {
                var $a = $(this),
                    $li = $a.parent(),
                    iStep = parseInt($a.attr("step"), 10),
                    sClass = "";

                if (iStep < currentStep) {
                    sClass += "jw-active ui-state-default";
                } else if (iStep === currentStep) {
                    sClass += "jw-current ui-state-highlight";
                } else if (iStep > currentStep) {
                    sClass += "jw-inactive ui-state-disabled";
                    $a.removeAttr("href");
                }
                $li.removeClass("jw-active jw-current jw-inactive ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-disabled").addClass(sClass);
            });
```

Underneath it, add the following code:

```
var title = $("ol .jw-current a").html();
$(".jw-button-next").attr("disabled", "disabled").removeClass("ui-state-hover"); 
validator(title);
```

First we're getting the name of the current page, then disabling the next button, then calling the validator function for the current title. Then we code the validator so that if the given conditions for the given page is satisfied, it would activate the next button again.

```
function validator(page)
    {
        switch(page){
            case "Page 1":
                if(... == true)
                   $(".jw-button-next").removeAttr("disabled");
            break;
            ....
        }
}
```